# Perform CRUD operation using Node.js and Redis

Tags: html, node.js, redis

I am looking for a way to connect to redis database from my node app and perform insert and display operation.

Requirement -

1. From UI textbox insert key value to redis DB
2. Display the key value on UI (textbox or table)

I am looking for an easy Node.js program to achieve the same. I don't have any code ready as of now. Just wanted to know the `app.js` part.

**app.js**

```
router.post('/route1', function(req, res)
{ 
    
    keyname= req.body.keyname;
    valuename= req.body.valuename;
    console.log(keyname);
    console.log(valuename);
    
    client.set(keyname, valuename, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(reply);
    });

    var redisValues = [];
    client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        if (keys) {
            async.map(keys, function (key, cb) {
                client.get(key, function (error, value) {
                    if (error) return cb(error);
                    var redisObj = {};
                    redisObj[key] = value;
                    redisValues.push(redisObj);
                    console.log(redisValues);
                    res.json({result1:redisValues});
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I get the below error for sending response more than once.

Error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install *node_redis* via npm using the following command.

```
npm install redis
```

Now connect with Redis from Node.js using the below code in app.js.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client
```

> By default, redis.createClient() will use *127.0.0.1* and *6379* as the
> hostname and port respectively. If you have a different host/port you
> can supply them as following:

```
var client = redis.createClient(port, host);
```

**Storing Key-Value Pairs**

All the Redis commands are exposed as different functions on the client object. To store a simple string use the following syntax:

```
client.set('framework', 'AngularJS');
```

You can also pass an optional callback to get a notification when the operation is complete:

```
client.set('framework', 'AngularJS', function(err, reply) {
  console.log(reply);
});
```

If the operation failed for some reason, the err argument to the callback represents the error. To retrieve the value of the key do the following:

```
client.get('framework', function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```

`client.get()` lets you retrieve a key stored in Redis. The value of the key can be accessed via the callback argument reply. If the key doesn’t exist, the value of reply will be empty.

Your will get all keys but with no values using below commands:

```
client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(keys[i]);
  }
});
```

You can get redis keys and values using below method:-

```
var redisValues = [];
    client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        if (keys) {
            async.map(keys, function (key, cb) {
                client.get(key, function (error, value) {
                    if (error) return cb(error);
                    var redisObj = {};
                    redisObj[key] = value;
                    redisValues.push(redisObj);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Everything works. However is there any way to get all key-value pair present in local redis? As `client.get('framework')` only fetches me the value of framework key

Comment: Updated the answer with your new requirement. Please upvote the answer if it works.

Comment: `console.log(keys[i]);` yet again gives all the keys but I want all the values as well. Keys and values both in JSON array if possible, will surely upvote this once my issue is resolved

Comment: I need values as well

Comment: I added on more function for getting values as well.

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look at it

Comment: any idea where I am going wrong? I know the reason as I am trying to send the response more than once in `async.map(keys..` but the array is inaccessible outside the function.

Comment: Would really appreciate if could take a look at the code.